# Is it common practice to not define the base template case of a function?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

The mindset is I only want to specialize a function for certain types. Is it common to just leave the base-template case empty or is there a better way?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void templated_function();

template<>
void templated_function<int>() {
  std::cout << "int template\n";
}

template<>
void templated_function<double>() {
  std::cout << "double template\n";
}

int main() {
  templated_function<int>();
  templated_function<double>();
}
```

I also came across deleted functions. Is this used very often in the context of templates?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void templated_function() = delete;

template<>
void templated_function<int>() {
  std::cout << "int template\n";
}

template<>
void templated_function<double>() {
  std::cout << "double template\n";
}

int main() {
  templated_function<int>();
  templated_function<double>();
}
```

Comment: Depending on if/what parameters the different versions take, it's sometimes better to use plain old function overloading here. If that's not an option then your way, or stick a `static_assert` into the base-template to control the error message.

Comment: Is it really a duplicate? My question is about function templates, not class templates

Comment: It's not a duplicate, but not for that reason. That question was asking "How do I ...?" and this is "Should I ... ?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is good practice to specialize a function only for certain types. The effect is a compile time error, when used with not specialized, i.e. not copy constructible types. Which is great. This way you make sure, that folks, who maintain your code later know, what your intention was. You might want to document the fact, that you deliberately chose not to implement a default behaviour.